# PHP - Diffrence between new Object vs new \Object?

Tags: php, oop

Everything is in the title. When I create my object with `new Object` I have an error saying that my Class is not found. But when I do `new \Object` everything is working like a charm. Hope someone can help me understand. Thank you in advance.

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: ty Amal for the link. I am digging into right now and will revert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience PHP now have namespace support in order to "package" or "sort" your objects into different "categories", this basically allows for easier auto-loading and relative dependency includes.

`\` is the root namespace which simply put means, use Object in "no namespace". This only comes in handy when an object in a sub-namespace requires an object unrelated to the current namespace, e.g:

`\HTTP\Request\Properties()` wants to extend the SPL object `ArrayObject`, if you would try to   `extend ArrayObject` this would fail because your current namespace is `\HTTP\Request`, and ArrayObject is located in the root namespace. In order to break out of the current namespace you'd have to `\` (root/break out) the namespace.

Namespaces are very helpful when you want to utilize different vendor packages, e.g Zend framework libraries or SwiftMailer, all you have to do is to publish an auto-loading procedure for all the vendor packages and continue working and implementing as demonstrated below:

```
/vendor/Zend/[zend packages]

$algos = \Zend\Crypt\Hash::getSupportedAlgorithms();
```

Comment: ty very much Daniel for the time taken to help me out. Cheers :)